# boolean in nested for loops

Tags: java, boolean

I'm a total newbie to the java world. I came across a code such as presented below:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    int x,y;
    boolean isprime;

    for (x=2; x<100; x++) {
        isprime=true;

        for (y=2; y<=x/y;y++) 

        if ((x%y)==0) isprime = false;
        if (isprime) System.out.println (x + " is a prime number");
    }   
}
```

My question is: Does the boolean `isprime=true` relate to the x in a way that each x is true unless later it is false if `x%y==0` ???

I don't quite get it.

Comment: Sounds like you get it to me. Basically they assume every x is prime unless the remainder of dividing x by y equals zero. So your explanation seems valid to me.

Comment: your second loop is not ok

Comment: @dit He didn't write the code.

Comment: it doesn't relate.  it just loops thru the numbers to find one without a remainder  (the %).  take the number 13.  it says if 2...13/13 doesnt have a remainder, then it is a prime.  compare that to 14.  2...14/14....when it gets to 7, there is no remainder, so it cannot be prime

Comment: You may start using curly braces always. Then you won't get confused by code like that. It's a very common reason for nasty bugs.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you have answered your own question correctly. Additionally, the spacing and lack of braces is confusing but a `for` loop without braces only affects the next line. This is what the code would look like with the curly braces included:

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    int x,y;
    boolean isprime;

    for (x=2; x<100; x++) {
        isprime=true;

        for (y=2; y<=x/y;y++) {
            if ((x%y)==0) isprime = false;
        }
        if (isprime) System.out.println (x + " is a prime number");
    }   
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: After setting isprime to false, you should break out of the inner do-loop - any further checks in that loop are superfluous.